# Remove subarray of array and convert into objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of arrays which I have to convert into an array of objects:

```json
[
  [
    {
      lable: "text",
      anotherValue: "anothervalue"
    }
  ], 
  [
    {
      lable: "text",
      anotherValue: "anothervalue"
    }
  ]
]
```

I need to convert this into:

```json
[
  {
    lable: "text",
    anotherValue: "another value"
  }, 
  {
    lable: "text",
    anotherValue: "another value"
  }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and in particular ask a question at all.  Don't forget to describe what you have already tried. Note that you can still edit your question. Invest some effort to remove parts like **strong text** or `enter code here` to increase the probability that someone will help you.

Comment: Use the map method, and pop out the last array element if there is always the last is rewuired for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using map. The function given to map as a parameter unpacks each subarray and replaces it by the object within.

```
a = [
  [{lable:'text',anotherValue:'anothervalue'}], 
  [{lable:'text',anotherValue:'anothervalue'}]
];

result = a.map((o) => o[0])
```